# DynamoDb select specific attributes using boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have DynamoDb table called `mydb` with below format where `id` is the partition key.
Other attributes to this table are `Name, timestamp, Address and Sex`. And my DB containers 10,000 record counts.

Now I would like to select specific attributes such as  `Id, Name and Address`,
So I follow these steps but none of them are showing me specific attributes. Can anyone point out how to fx this?

```
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')
paginator = dynamodb_client.get_paginator('query')
```

Step1 :

```
for page in paginator.paginate(TableName='mydb',
                               Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
                               AttributesToGet=[
                                   'Id',
                                   'Address',
                                   'Name'
                               ]):
     ....
```

complains about `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Either the **KeyConditions** or **KeyConditionExpression** parameter must be specified in the request.`  I thought it make sense and hence I moved to Step2.

Step 2:
Since there are no conditions necessary for my query. I thought, adding the condition `id >= 1` would help. Because `Id` in my table starts with 1 and keeps incremented.

```
for page in paginator.paginate(TableName='mydb',
                               Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
                               AttributesToGet=[
                                   'Id',
                                   'Name',
                                   'Address'
                               ],
                               KeyConditions={
                                   'Id': {
                                       'AttributeValueList': [{"N": str(1)}],
                                       'ComparisonOperator': 'GE'
                                   }
                               }):
        ......
Now, it throws me `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported`
```

Now I don't understand, I have added `KeyConditions` because in step1 it suggest to add either one of them.

So, what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you the problem is `when calling the Query operation`. Indeed, the `Query` operation is the operation used to scan only a single partition, and it **requires** this partition's key, with either the `KeyConditions` or `KeyConditionExpression` parameter. But you don't want to scan a single partition, you want to scan the *entire* table. So you neeed to use the `Scan` operation, not `Query`.

So, you need to pass `scan`, not `query`, to the paginator, and everything should (hopefully) work as you expected.